# How to format label with lots of text next to radio input without word wrap?

Tags: html, css

How can I get a `<label>` that has lots of text to display next to a radio input, without wrapping that text around the input.

In this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JXrHh/1/

I use `display: inline block;` to get the format I want. But that will only work if the text is broken up with `<br/>` tags. Otherwise the text will drop below the radio input.

Without `display: inline block;` the text will wrap around the radio input.

I must be missing some small detail somewhere, can anyone help point it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can alternatively use `display: table-cell;` on the `<label>` elements and there is no need to specify a width as the content will determine it:

http://jsfiddle.net/JXrHh/5

Comment: neat, this is even better with no need to force a width

Comment: @JamesMontagne: Yes - Updated, sorry about that!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JXrHh/5/ put this one in your answer, you still haven't gotten the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

If you set a fixed width to your `inline-block` element then you do not need explicit line breaks:

http://jsfiddle.net/JXrHh/3/

```
label.inline {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: ah, I knew it was something simple that I was overlooking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it's just a small thing.
if you have enough space you don't want to be a limited.
you can spread as wide as you wish .so limit it

```
label.inline {
display: inline-block;
width:200px;
```

}